# psql command giving error macOS

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

I installed it using EnterpriseDB installer. The installation went fine but I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Comment: it seems to be looking foe a file called ./config/app.yml. that's not nornal, almost certainly an OSX thing.

Comment: @Jasen: This is definitely no macOS thing, because `psql` is a binary and not Javascript.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, the error messages come from a javascript file...  I can't be sure that psql isn't a script. eg: on debian it is shell script. the binary is in a different location and the script execs it.

Comment: probably this probvlem is OSX or EnterpriseDB specific.